# Selecting two meshes in Edit mode

Tags: selection-tools

why can't i select two objects in edit mode?     I am trying to make a face from two different[image] meshes but can't perform the action

Comment: please delete this question as it is an exact duplicate of the one you asked just a few minutes prior to this

Comment: @NicolaSap Page will be down within a day, the moderators get points for cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Go to object mode, select both objects, Ctrl J to join them, then go to edit mode.